# How to make FloatingButton stick to the bottom of WebView inside CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I need to make **FloatingActionButton** always stick to the bottom of my fragment where I display **WebView**. The problem is that the button in my current XML is cut in half and I can't manage to fix it. Here is my layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundWhite"
    tools:context=".fragments.CpuComparisionFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_compare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fb_margin_16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fb_margin_16dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_compare" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong? Any ideas how to fix this? Here is screenshot how my app looks now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the android version installed on the device you're testing your app on doesn't support some of your xml attributes. Anyways, replace the FAB code with the below snippet. I hope it work for you.

```
     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/button_compare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fb_margin_16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fb_margin_16dp"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_compare" />
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: Same situation. This don't change anything. The Button is still cut in a half. :/

Comment: Goto manifest and change your app theme to something like this @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`  to your FrameLayout .

Comment: That does not help :(

Comment: ok. try adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to Coordinator layout as well as webView.

Comment: also can you mention on which device you are testing it .

Comment: I've added it to CoordinatorLayout aswell but that does not change anything. I am testing it on Nexus 5X emulator on ARM x86 API 23.

Comment: Can you confirm that if it is only the button that is pushed down and not the whole fragment?